# How can BITOP command in redis working when compare boolean operation on two strings

Tags: redis, boolean-logic

I am following BITOP command in redis.
http://redis.io/commands/bitop.
While using snippet command as bellow:

```
redis> SET key1 "foobar"
OK
redis> SET key2 "abcdef"
OK
redis> BITOP AND dest key1 key2
(integer) 6
redis> GET dest
"`bc`ab"
```

Why `BITOP AND dest key1 key2` return (integer) 6 ? Is it the length of the key `dest`. And why result of key `dest` is `"'bc'ab"`. Because in mathematic theory, I never seen AND operation between two strings. Can anyone explain me the way to AND two strings ? Thanks so much !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[BITOP](http://redis.io/commands/bitop) command does bitwise operations on binary representations of any  strings you provide.

*Why BITOP AND dest key1 key2 return (integer) 6 ? Is it the length of the key dest*

Yes it is. From doc :

> Return value
>       Integer reply
>       The size of the string stored in the destination key, that is equal to the size of the longest input string.

*I never seen AND operation between two strings. Can anyone explain me the way to AND two strings ?*

AND or any bitwise operation between two strings means same operation between binary representations of these strings, and if the strings are of unequal length in their binary representation, the shorter strings are padded with zeroes on the left to match the larger string ( done in redis BITOP too ).

Binary representations of "foobar" and "abcdef" are ( spaces for clarity):

```
"foobar" : 01100110 01101111 01101111 01100010 01100001 01110010 
"abcdef" : 01100001 01100010 01100011 01100100 01100101 01100110
```

Now you can perform any bitwise operation on them and then convert the resulting bits to string representation.